# Injecting variable from jenkins into jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am using a password parameter option in jenkins pipeline job where i store a password and need to inject that into the environment of jenkins file

[image]

Here is the part of the jenkins file where i am trying to inject this `PASS`

```
pipeline {
     agent any
      environment {
        USER= 'abcd'
        PW= '${params.PASS}'
    }
    stages {
        stage('staring tests') {
```

When i try echo-ing $PW, it just echoes ${params.PASS}.

Any pointers will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

In Groovy Strings are single quotes. They cannot be interpolated with variables. You would need to concatenate strings and values. i.e. `PW='pass' + myVar`

GStrings are double quotes. http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GString.html

So you would need to change it to `PW="${params.PASS}"` and this would interpolate the variable into the string.

However since your not doing any interpolation in that example, you don't need to use GStrings either. Whereever you need access to that value just call it directly `echo params.PASS`

Answer (score 0):

You should not put a 'params' value into an environment variable. It won't work for you. The environment sections initialize only string variables, therefore, it initializes your PW with a pure string of ${params.PASS} since it does no 'calculations' for it.
Instead, in your pipeline, just use the params.PASS directly in your code.